# parse a text file and get an array kind of array ( "(0:00)" => "text1", "(0:30)" => "text2")

Tags: php

I have a text file

```
(0:00)

text1

text2

(0:30)

text text text text text
```

..................

the result should be like this

```
array("(0:00)"=>"text1 text2","(0:30)"=>"text text text text text")
```

my code

```
$key = array();
    $val = array();
    $out = array();
    $file = file('1.txt');
    foreach($file as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (preg_match("/(\d{0,2}:\d\d)/",$line,$match)){
            $key[]=$match;
        }else{
            $val[]=$match;
        }
        $out=array_merge($key,$val);
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($out);
```

tell me, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = file_get_contents('1.txt');
preg_match_all("~\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)~", $text, $keys);
$values = array_values(preg_grep("~.+~", preg_split("~\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)~", $text)));
$final = [];
for ($n = 0; $n < count($keys[0]); $n++) {
    $final[$keys[0][$n]] = $values[$n];
}
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$n = preg_match_all('/\((\d{0,2}:\d\d)\)([\s+]*?)([^\(]*)/mi', $file, $matches);

$out = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); ++$i)
{
                            // for removing newline characters:
    $out[$matches[1][$i]] = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $matches[3][$i])); 
}

var_dump($out);
```

At first i tried it with the way you were going, but using one regex for both seemed to be much easier.

It gave me following result:

```
array(2) {
  ["0:00"]=>
  string(11) "text1 text2"
  ["0:30"]=>
  string(24) "text text text text text"
}
```

Comment: Okay, but if the string contains text1 text2 (text3) the regexp stop at text2 and does not recieve (text3), how to fix?

Comment: Is there a character which is not allowed in your text?

Comment: Allow all characters

Comment: Well i tried it now for a long time and since im not that good at regex i couldnt come up with a fixed version. Keep in mind, that users may write something like (1:23) in the text, which would be matched as well. One more thing: I´d recommend using a database for things like that (makes it easier) or saving the data in a format which you can simply extract (maybe base64 or serializing, which would not interrupt matching the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array looking for the first key, and then add all occurences to this key until you find next.

Also, your code had several logical errors:

`$key[]=$match;` - $match is an array, you should use the first occurence

`$val[]=$match;` - `$match` is empty in this case (match wasn't found), you should use the `$line`

---

Corrected code:

```
$out = array();
$key = "";
$file = file('aaa.txt');
foreach($file as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if(empty($line)) continue;
    if (preg_match("/(\d{0,2}:\d\d)/",$line,$match)){
        $key = $match[0];
        continue;
    }
    if(!empty($key)){
        $out[$key] = $line;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```